# Sending http request behind nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy, jersey-client

I am not sure how to formulate my question but here we go:

I have 2 servers, one is the nginx reverse proxy and one is the app server.

In my app server, I am developing a simple http client using jerseyclient that will send a request to another server. I can do this now but the traffic goes from the app server and directly to the destination. Is it possible to it from the app server, passes through the reverse proxy server and goes to the destination?

And, is this design ok or is it an abomination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nginx reverse proxy works only for requests outside your network. 
To configure your system works as you described you have to configure firewall NAT or caching HTTP proxy like *squid* etc. 
If you have no reasons why your servers should look as single computer - your configuration is OK.

Comment: thanks nredko. Do you mind sharing some stuff regarding what you have said? I'd like to research more about it. Thanks!

Comment: This highly depends on specific network configuration and goals you need to achieve